# How do RVM rubies find gems?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I'm using Ruby 1.8.6 under RVM on Mac OS X (10.9.2). I installed everything as a local user (not root), and then installed a gem using:

```
gem install gli -v 1.6
```

When I run a ruby with `require('gli')`, I get the error:

```
in `require': no such file to load -- gli (LoadError)
```

even though `gem list` shows `gli (1.6.0)`.

I don't know exactly how RVM does its gemsets, but there is no `gli.rb` file in any of the directories in the `$LOAD_PATH`.

How does RVM interact with the `$LOAD_PATH` to find the necessary gems in the gemset?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the ruby installed with RVM?

Comment: Pretty sure. `ruby --version` is 1.8.6, and my system ruby is 2.0.0.

Comment: What does `$ which ruby` outputs?

Comment: `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `require 'rubygems'` at the top of your source file. In 1.8 rubygems aren't required by default.

Thus said, regarding gem paths:

`GEM_HOME` indicates where gems are installed. To find out what it is for your case do:

```
$ echo $GEM_HOME
```

This should display an RVM-related path, since RVM changes this environment variable in order to make the `$ gem install` command install gems in its directories.

Comment: Shouldn't RVM then add `$GEM_HOME` to the ruby `$LOAD_PATH`? How else is ruby supposed to know where to find the installed gems?

Comment: Nope. `$LOAD_PATH` and `$GEM_HOME` are two different things and they are both set by each ruby you install, whether it comes from RVM or it's system ruby.

Comment: So I should manually add $GEM_HOME to the load path when I call ruby (e.g., ruby -I"$GEM_HOME" script.rb)?

Comment: Add a `require 'rubygems'` to the top of your file.

Comment: It looks like this is a specific requirement for Ruby 1.8: Note: For Ruby 1.8 you must require 'rubygems' before requiring any gems (http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/).