# RVM Can't Find Gems

Tags: rubygems, environment-variables, rvm

I looked at the following: 
[How do RVM rubies find gems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257965/how-do-rvm-rubies-find-gems)

And think the advice there might be helpful, e.g.

require 'rubygems'

$ echo $GEM_HOME

but could use some advice on how to apply - my ruby file does have the

require 'rubygems'

directive specified before requiring other gems (which can't be found) ... I get errors like this in the error log:

```
    /var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- /var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/json-2.0.1/lib/json/ (LoadError)
from /var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from printers.rb:14:in `<main>'

    /var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
from /var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:32:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
from /var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

I am not setting $GEM_HOME anywhere, several rubies are installed for people to use on a shared web server (and the scripts are ultimately accessed via the web / Apache). The scripts refer to the proper rvm ruby - for example,

```
    #!/var/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby
```

In order to get user scripts to work, the full path to required gems must be specified, for example,

```
    require "/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/json-stream-0.2.1/lib/json/stream"
    require "/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri
```

and in many cases, the gem .rb files, need to be edited to specify full paths to the files they themselves require.

The rvm environments / gems are installed on each of 4 web servers which all mount a global (nfs) filesystem where the ruby script itself lives. Maybe this is making it hard for the ruby to know where to find gems? Can I set some environment variable in the script to help? In an earlier script I used unshift to workaround the issue like this :

```
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/addressable-2.3.8/lib/')
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/css_parser-1.3.6/lib/')
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/htmlentities-4.3.4/lib/')
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/')
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/')
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/premailer-1.8.4/lib/')
    $:.unshift('/var/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/webrick-1.3.1/lib/')

    require 'rubygems'
    require 'test/unit'
    require 'webrick'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'premailer'
```

Thanks for any info on the best way to address,

SM